# IntelliJ still using old dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am currently using Intellij Idea 2020.2.4.

I want to replace a dependency with a newer version of itself.
I replaced

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company.digital.fmk</groupId>
  <artifactId>dgt-security</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.24</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company.digital.fmk</groupId>
  <artifactId>dgt-security</artifactId>
  <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I've checked that in the effective pom, the version has changed to the new value. However, after running
`mvn -U clean install`, when I click on a class from the dependency, it still shows the old version.
When I try to delete the old version from the project structure, it says that it is still used in a module, even though I can't find the old version number anywhere in the project.
I can't manually delete the old library from my local folder, because it is used in another project.

Other answers have suggested using Maven -> Reimport, but I didn't find this in my intellij

What can I do to make intellij use the new dependency version in my project ?

**EDIT**

When I right-click on a project and select Maven, here are my options:

- Reload project (already tried, did not work)
- Generate sources and update folders
- Ignore projects
- Unlink maven projects
- Open 'settings.xml'
- Create 'profiles.xml'
- Download sources
- Download documentation
- Download sources and documentation
- Show effective pom
- Show diagram
- Show diagram popup

Comment: Going to ask the obvious question: why haven't you tried to remove the dependency from the POM directly?  (Project Structure is built off of the POM, so it'd likely be recreated if you just deleted it from there within IntelliJ.)

Comment: I did, sorry if that wasn't clear in my question. Please see my edit

Comment: You need to reimport inside IntelliJ. If you changed the POM, there should be refresh button hovering in the upper-right corner of the pom.xml, and otherwise you can reimport from the Maven tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to your Maven repository:
.m2/com/company/digital/fmk
Delete jar files
Rerun command, it will download dependencies again.

Comment: Ok that worked, but can't it be automated ?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-255594. Does this problem remain every time you change this dependency version? Do you see it only with this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project -> maven ->   sync  shall do the trick
previous versions did this by default on changes in pom.xml
now it seems to be not available anymore

Comment: Hello, please see my edit: I don't have the sync entry...

Comment: File - invalidate caches / restart ?  Your dependency is the same version, or a new one?